# Will I have trouble running a bathroom fan 10 CFM (25%) stronger than needed?

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, exhaust-fan

My bathroom measures in at 289 cubic feet.  Dividing that by 7.5 and rounding up gives me a target fan capacity of 40 CFM.  However, there are many more fans available at 50 CFM.

I read this post, [Are there drawbacks to installing a stronger bath fan?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86492/are-there-drawbacks-to-installing-a-stronger-bath-fan), stating that a fan moving more air than necessary can inhibit appliance fumes from venting properly, not the mention the HVAC efficiency hit from expelling conditioned air.

My question is this: will increasing from 40 to 50 CFM create such problems, or is that in the realm of a much bigger increase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An extra 10 CFM won't hurt you at all.... If anything, it will get rid of the unwanted moisture faster. I'd wager that article was meant for much larger bathroom fans.

Comment: Thanks @JACK.  How much higher than target do you reckon would create problems?

Comment: @zwiebelspaetzle  Well, let me just say I have a bathroom  about the same size as yours  and I put in a 120 CFM fan. I like a lot of noise when I'm in there. I actually would have gone higher but then I would have had to change the duct. When you think about it, they don't stay on for a long time.